# Page returns ID of subcategory even when on main category

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, categories

Imagine having a category `ANIMALS (ID 1)` that have child category `DOGS (ID 2)` and category `DOGS` have child category `BIG DOGS (ID 3)`. Then you have post "Labrador" in category `BIG DOGS` (so it is in category with ID 3).

Now, on webpage of category `DOGS` you show all posts withing this category and its child categories, so now it shows post "Labrador". You need to find out ID of currently displayed category.

So you're browsing webpage of category `DOGS` therefore you expect code

```
get_the_category()
```

will return ID 2. Unfortunatelly it returns category ID of last added post, so you get ID 3 :(

Question is, **how to get ID of currently displayed category that is not top parent and have subcategories with posts**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One post can have many categories (in your case will have also parent cat.) ->so, you cannot have singular answer. You can either check if it is in category:

```
if (in_category('Cities')) {...}
```

or list all of categories post is in (and then check):

```
$arrayListOfCategories = wp_get_post_categories( $post_id)
```

all levels of tree have posts, even if if you have select only the last level,
maybe a solution for you will be to chose which level of the tree you wan to show, this will do the trick,

```
   $arrayListOfCategories = wp_get_post_categories($post_id);
   foreach ($arrayListOfCategories as $category){
    if (count(get_category_parents( $category, false, '>' )) > count($allchildren)) $allchildren = get_category_parents( $category, false, '>' ) ; 
   }
   $catTreeLevels = explode(">", $allchildren);
   echo $allchildren ." for ex. chosen 1: ".$catTreeLevels[1];
```

ref.:
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/in_category
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_post_categories

Comment: Hi Michal, thank you for your answer, unfortunatelly I'm not trying to get category of a post. I need to get category ID of a currently displayed page. Problem is that when I'm on page of Country with lastly added post New York, code get_the_category() doesn't show ID of category Country (even though I'm on its page), but instead it shows ID of category Cities in which is lastly added post New York. I'll try to update my first post to be more clear (it is hard to explain the problem :) ).

Comment: page has no such value as category, post is present in all parent categories, see a solution (edited) above

Comment: Thank you for your hints Michal, based on that I tried different approach and find solution :)

Comment: if my help were useful, I'll appreciate your click in accept button above :)

Answer (score 0):

Finaly I found a solution - I don't check ID of a category but it's

```
single_cat_title
```

that returns correct value no matter what (and that can be used to find category ID if needed).

I hope it'll help anybody else dealing with the same problem.